# Do wheels equal Chinese engineer always say `别自己造轮子` 's 轮子?

Tags: terminology

I read a page said:

> The extensions are Python wheels that you can run as CLI commands.

Is the wheels meaning `framworks or tools` ?
and is it Chinese engineer always say `别自己造轮子` 's 轮子 from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wheels" are [a name for binary packages](https://pythonwheels.com/) in Python. It's not a recognized English word, however, just one that the developers of that system came up with.